# The exact location with the help of GPS in a rectangular coordinate system (android)

Tags: android, gps

In my application I need to calculate the distance between two gps devices.
When using a GPS coordinates (longitude, latitude, altitude) there is a problem:
The height is determined with greater absolute error. You can verify this by calculating the error
phi and tetta (latitude and longitude) on the basis of formulas

`x = r*sin(tetta)*cos(phi)
y = r*sin(tetta)*cos(phi)
z = r*cos(tetta)`

However, it is obvious that the GPS receiver is at the beginning accepts data in a Cartesian coordinate system (x, y, z), and then translates them
the system of coordinates r, tetta, phi (altitude, latitude, longitude).
How can I get the original coordinates x,y,z? Are there existing methods in the API? Once again, I don't need conversion formulas
from a spherical coordinate system in a rectangular, I need the accuracy of the original data obtained from a GPS receiver. Is it possible?

Comment: For what you need the distance? short distances < 1km, verly long 2000km? which kind of vehicle? car, or aeroplane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right the GPS receiver internally uses the [ECEF Coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF), which is cartesian.
But you cannot get that coordinates on a smartphone. See the above link for conversion from WGS84 coordinates you get in the smartphone to ECEF.

But be warned ECEF this is a 3d cartesian, so the direct line between two points will cut through the earth, that is usefull only for flight applications.

For vehicles (cars, ships) normally you should forget the height of an GPS, just calculate the ground distance (2d- cartesian).

Another solution: first do a (lat,lon) to 2-d cartesian conversion with units meter, then add the height as 3d dimension, this then modells a small part of the earth as flat.

It always depends for whoich purpose you need the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it obvious that the GPS starts with Cartesian coordinates?

In any case, I'm not seeing a way to get the accuracy of a particular element of the location from the API. It is true that altitude tends to be most error prone (and depends on chipset and is above the reference geoid rather than anything physical). You could get some indication of accuracy by recording data for altitude and modelling the variation.

Comment: At least that would be logical. Let the selected rectangular coordinate system associated with the center of the Earth. Knowing the distance between the gps receiver and three gps satellites you can define the position of the gps receiver. In this approach, there is no reason, by which the accuracy z-coordinates (conditionally height) would be more errors along the x and y axes. If we consider the transformation equations Cartesian coordinate system in a spherical coordinate system (gps), then: d(phi) / dx = 1/r dr/dx

Comment: (the error in the height of the r-times more than the error in latitude). This is consistent with the figures that I get on my tablet